# Set Column BackColor in Datagridview to override Row BackColor in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

working in vb.net in Visual Studio on a datagridview.

The rows are days of the week. The rows all alternate backcolor (variables LightColour1 and LightColour2), then the weekend rows are variable WeekendRowsColour. That's all easy enough, but now I have to make the entire final column white. But I can't seem to override the row colors no matter how I approach it. Any advice?

Here's my code section:

```
For r = 0 To 27
    dgv.Rows.Add()
    dgv.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value = Format(nDate, "ddd")
    dgv.Rows(r).Cells(1).Value = Format(nDate, "d/MM/yyyy")
    If Format(nDate, "ddd") = "Sat" Or Format(nDate, "ddd") = "Sun" Then
        dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = WeekendRowsColour
        dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = WeekendRowsSelColour
    Else
        If r Mod 2 = 0 Then 'even row
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = LightColour1
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SelLightColour1
        Else 'alternate row
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = LightColour2
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SelLightColour2
        End If
    End If
    nDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, nDate)
Next
dgv.Columns(dgv.Columns.Count - 1).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
```

But no matter how I approach it, the last column comes out the default color. My best success has been setting the backcolor and alternatingrowsbackcolor of the rows programmatically, and setting the column properties to white in the designer, but that doesn't overwrite the alternating rows or the weekend colors.

Pulling my hair out here!

Comment: Maybe a custom class for that last column with backcolor that is not overwritable? Not sure how to do that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set it inside the loop per cell like this:

```
For r = 0 To 27
    dgv.Rows.Add()
    dgv.Rows(r).Cells(0).Value = Format(nDate, "ddd")
    dgv.Rows(r).Cells(1).Value = Format(nDate, "d/MM/yyyy")
    If Format(nDate, "ddd") = "Sat" Or Format(nDate, "ddd") = "Sun" Then
        dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = WeekendRowsColour
        dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = WeekendRowsSelColour
    Else
        If r Mod 2 = 0 Then 'even row
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = LightColour1
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SelLightColour1
        Else 'alternate row
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = LightColour2
            dgv.Rows(r).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = SelLightColour2
        End If
    End If
    nDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, nDate)

    dgv.Rows(r).Cells(dgv.Columns.Count-1).Style.BackColor = Color.White
Next
```

Comment: BLOODY LEGEND! I was trying to do that, but I was looking for a DefaultCellStyle property of the cell. Thank you, huge help!